# Why does sourcing a script with "set var = value" break $@?

Tags: linux, shell, centos, command-line-arguments

I am trying to configure auto logout on my Centos VM. I have noticed that if I create a file at /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh with only `set autologout = 30` in the file, then it breaks passing arguments for any script that sources /etc/profile.

A sample script that shows this is:

```
#!/bin/bash 
source /etc/profile 
echo ${@}
```

When I run it, the script only sees the arguments "autologout 30" and it doesn't get any parameter I try to pass it when running it.

This occurs regardless of the name of the autologout script, the name of the property, or if I have `set autologout 30` instead.

Can someone please explain what is happening? It is as if autologout.sh is hijacking the arguments. I am at a loss for what is happening, and researching profile.d and the set command has turned up nothing.

Comment: BTW, `(( $# )) && printf '%q\n' "$@"` is a much more reliable way to list your command-line arguments in bash. With `echo $@` (or its exact but unnecessarily-verbose equivalent `echo ${@}`), you can't tell the difference between `yourscript foo bar` and `yourscript "foo bar"`; moreover, due to the lack of quoting, `yourscript '*'` will have `echo $@` emit a list of files, instead of a `*` character; `echo "$@"` would fix this, but leave the other issues outstanding.

Comment: (Also, sourcing `/etc/profile` from scripts is generally bad form -- making your scripts depend on host-local configuration makes them nonportable by definition).

Comment: Tip: Consider running scripts with confusing behavior through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net). In this case, it would have automatically flagged [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2121)

Comment: @FreakyDan : Please look at the bash man page for the `set` command in the section *SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS*: First, setting an option is done by `set -o NAME VALUE`. Secondly, there is no *autologout* option in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set` is not used to modify shell variables in POSIX-compliant shells. Rather, when given positional arguments, it modifies the command-line argument list.

If you just want to assign a value to a variable, don't use `set`. Instead, your file should just contain:

```
autologout=30
```

...and `"$@"` will remain in its original state.